# How do I create subdomain names dynamically?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, python, subdomain, url

I would like to be able to create and remove subdomain name dynamically using scripting languages such as PHP, Python, Perl or others. I am using Apache as a web server

Example:

```
http://subdomain.example.com
http://subdomain2.example.com
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can make a CNAME entry/ A Record in your DNS settings, for each subdomain

> A CNAME record is a record in your
>   Domain Management Settings that allows
>   you to control a subdomain of your
>   domain.

**To automate it** along with registration, you can write a script which is executed for each user, when s/he registers.

You can refer to this link, as well, for a step-by-step process for Apache:

**[How to setup subdomains in apache](http://www.varslashlog.com/2008/10/31/how-to-setup-subdomains-in-apache/)**

**Alternate Solution**

You can also refer to an easier  [wildcard solution, **given by Alnitak**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321259/how-to-setup-sub-domains-like-blogspot#321292).

> You can either use a specific DNS
>   (`CNAME` or `A`/`AAAA`) entry for each
>   known subdomain, or a wild-card DNS
>   entry that'll accept *.example.com:
>
> ```
> $ORIGIN example.com
> foo     IN A 12.34.6.78
> bar     IN A 12.34.6.78
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> $ORIGIN example.com
> *       IN A 12.34.6.78
> ```
>
> The advantage of this latter is that
>   no changes are required to either DNS
>   or Apache configuration once the
>   service is running.  The disadvantage
>   is that all such wildcard lookups must
>   (by definition) end up returning the
>   same IP address.
>
> The Apache configuration will depend
>   on your requirements, both for
>   end-user control and security.  Note
>   that if the users have permission to
>   run CGI scripts on the server then
>   additional setup will be needed to
>   ensure that that's done securely.
>
> Depending on whether content is static
>   or dynamic this will also affect your
>   configuration:
>
> 1. Use [`mod_vhost_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) to map individual virtual hosts into their
>      individual directories on the server.
> 2. If you **really** want, create a separate `<VirtualHost>` section for
>      each known site, but then you'll have
>      to restart Apache each time a new user
>      signs up
> 3. Use a single `<VirtualHost>` and then look at the hostname part of the
>      requested URL (from the `$SERVER_NAME`
>      environment variable) in the scripts
>      that render the output to figure out
>      which user's content to display.

Comment: First link dead of this date — which is exactly why this should be an *answers* site, not a link to answers site.

Answer (score 1):

The creation of subdomains is built into Apache, look into mass vhosting. Specifically: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

All you'll need to do then is come up with a convention, and then have your script create directories when needed. But, technically you want to start with the apache mass vhost configuration setup.

Comment: The need for an A record for *.example.com is also worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a DNS question, not an Apache one unless you have a *.example.com record pointing to said webserver. If the client can't resolve subdomain??.example.com, the webserver is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Don't actually create the subdomains, but instead just use a wildcard subdomain so you can have http://anything.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I've used in a python website is to inspect the subdomain in a middleware.  Then I check that against the database of subdomains and if I find a match I set a request level setting telling the code what subdomain I'm looking at.

It's really fairly clean and can work very well.  My site currently supports form than 350 dynamic subdomains.